# BigQuery: Calculating averages in daily partitioned tables

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a problem with getting averages out of several partitioned daily tables. We have partitioned tables for every day. I want to have an SQL query that calculates requests average for N days grouped by country.

So this is the schema:

date (string)
country (string)
req (integer)

What I have until now:

```
SELECT country, avg(req) as AvgReq
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([thePartitionedTable_],
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -2, 'DAY'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
GROUP BY country
```

This works for 1 day of course, but the data is skewed when i try it for 2 or more days. What is the problem in my logic? How does the AVG() function work in this case? Do i need to group by date as well?

So i want the daily average of thePartitionedTable_today and daily average thePartitionedTable_yesterday then i want the average of their averages if that makes sense. So if thePartitionedTable_today has a daily average of 2 for Nigeria and thePartitionedTable_yesterday had a daily average of 3 for Nigeria, then the average for Nigeria of those two days should be 2.5. I really appriciate your time!

Comment: AVG gets an average of all your data for example if 1 day you do 10 sales for $30 total you get **$3** average for that day if the second date you do 2 sales for $4 total is a **$2** average for that day but the total would be 12 sales for $34 total for an Average of **$2.83**

Comment: Ah so I was kinda right by assuming why the data is skewed, so I do need to write a better query that calculates averages by day and then takes the average from those averages. I got some work to do, I hope someone will help, but I'll surely post an answer here if I find it!

Comment: I would suggest working with [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql) instead if possible--if you have complex logic, it becomes much harder to write using legacy SQL. Here you would use a [table wildcard](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) to read from multiple tables at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using standard SQL:

```
with avg_byday AS (
  SELECT
    country,
    AVG(req) AS req_avg
  FROM
    `thePartitionedTable_*`
  GROUP BY
    _TABLE_SUFFIX,
    country)
SELECT
  country,
  AVG(req_avg)
FROM
  avg_byday
GROUP BY
  country
```

The subquery will also give you average requests per country for each day.

Comment: This is really readable and not at all what I was doing. Didn't even know about the "with" syntax or the _TABLE_SUFFIX used with *. Thank you so much!